# Visual Studio crashes when opening PDF for second time

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, process, itext

I have a bit of a strange problem, in my program, when I open a PDF file using the following command:

```
 Process.Start("test.pdf");
```

the first time, the file is opened just fine, but the second time I use this command on ANY pdf file, at ANY position in the code, vshost.exe crashes.

My next step was to disable vshost, with vshost disabled, the application its self crashes.

When I say 'crashes' I mean it says that it has stopped responding.

If I create a new project, it works just fine, so it must be something wrong with my project?

I am using the `iTextSharp` library at other points in the code to create the pdfs, could this be a cause?

I realise this problem is very general but I have no idea what could be causing it so I dont know what information to provide.

More info:

When I look at the output of the debugger after the program crashes it says "The program '[4320] SmartShelf.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."

Edit: Does anybody know any other way of viewing a pdf using c#?

Comment: Why are you starting a process with `"test.pdf"`??? A process must be an executable and a `pdf` is no executable...

Comment: @bash.d: `Process.Start` is a wrapper for `ShellExecute`, which accepts a document name and finds the associated application.

Comment: But there must be some other way... This is hillarious

Comment: @MarkH don't have a solution, but I just remember some similar issue I had, and the cause of the issue was Adobe Reader with some specific version. Did you try to change default pdb viewer and see if this will fix your problem?

Comment: I dont mind how the PDF is opened so if anybody knows another method I can use I will give that a go.

Comment: @MarkH are you doing any work on the PDF with iTextSharp?  If you are, are you closing everything properly before you open the PDF?  Are you disposing of objects that implement IDisposable?

Comment: @outcoldman I changed the default program to windows viewer and now it crashes on the 3rd time. We are making progress!

Comment: @JohnKoerner the problem happens even if none of the itextsharp commands are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not perfect, my solution in the end was to display the pdf in a webBrowser control, by setting the URL to the path of the PDF using

`webBrowser1.Navigate("asdf.pdf");`

this displayed it in adobe reader but within a web browser.

This solution suited my needs absolutely fine (if not better) and doesn't cause the application to crash. Thanks for everybody's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use using context or the dispose command to get rid of any open file connections before calling the start("asdf.pdf") and see if that takes care of it.

Also make sure your process is running as admin in win7.
And another thing you can try is use process.start(cmd, "aspdf.pdf") this way your starting a command window and it calls the pdf starter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I make sure that a process is running as admin? 

Also process.start("cmd", "aspdf.pdf") just starts command line. not the pdf Im afraid.

Comment: one thing you can do also is create a bat file and process.start the batch file. and test the batch file to run the pdf.